# Ignition 8.1 reporting module: Report not displaying row-0 of table

Tags: ignition

I have configured a simple report which is running a named query. In the preview tab, (on the right-hand side, in the raw data browser) I can see that my query is returning all rows, but in the actual report, I am missing row-0.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the table and reconfigured a new one the same way and that worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).